# Spring boot OAuth2 Server with AZURE B2C authentication

Tags: azure, spring-boot, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a Spring web application that uses Oauth2 for authentication, we have Oauth server to where the web applications redirect to and perform the form-based login. I am trying to find a way to integrate the Oauth server with Azure AD B2C i.e authentication should be done against the Azure AD B2C but the access token generation should happen in the Oauth server.

Is there a way to configure Oauth server to perform the Authentication against the Azure AD B2C?

Comment: There is no question here, no indication of the problem, and no way to reproduce the unstated problem.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenID Connect as the authentication protocol.You can add custom OpenID Connect identity providers into your user flows.

[image]

See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp) for more details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.